# Python tkinter: Using a "textvariable" in a combobox seems useless

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter

Using the `textvariable` attribute when creating a combobox in tkinter seems completely useless.  Can someone please explain what the purpose is?  I looked in the Tcl documentation and it says `textvariable` is used to set a default value, but it looks like in tkinter you would just use the `.set` method to do that.

**Example showing what I mean:**

This doesn't work...

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

master = Tk()

test = StringVar()
country = ttk.Combobox(master, textvariable=test)
country['values'] = ('USA', 'Canada', 'Australia')
country.pack()

# This does not set a default value...
test="hello"

mainloop()
```

This does work.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

master = Tk()

country = ttk.Combobox(master)
country['values'] = ('USA', 'Canada', 'Australia')
country.pack()

# This does set a default value.
country.set("hello")

mainloop()
```

If you are supposed to just use the `.set` and `.get` methods, what is the point of assigning anything to `textvariable`?  Every example online seems to use `textvariable`, but why?  It seems completely pointless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under normal circumstances *there is no reason to use a `StringVar`*. I have no idea why most tutorials show it. It adds overhead but provides no extra value. As you observe, you can directly get and set the value of the combobox via the combobox object itself.

The advantage to using a `StringVar` comes when you want to either a) have two widgets share the same variable so that one is updated when the other is changed, or b) attach one or more traces to the `StringVar`. Both of those are uncommon, but are sometimes quite useful.

Comment: Now it makes sense.  That's the kind of explanation I was looking for. Thanks Bryan!

Comment: Indeed. Practical example, I have a combobox with search results. The combobox only displays the titles of the search results (in this case: the keys of a dictionary), but below that I want to display a description, date, and source o the search result (elements of the dictionary). So I want to track changes of the Stringvar, so that I can display the extra information. Very practical!

Answer (score 7):

Since Python has no type safety, you're overwriting the reference to the `StringVar` object with a string. To set the value, call the `set` method:

```
test = StringVar()
country = ttk.Combobox(master, textvariable=test)
#...
test.set("hello")
```

Comment: Okay that makes more sense.  Why not just use set on the combobox object itself though?  I still don't see the point of adding the extra variable.

Comment: The variable gets updated when the content of the Combobox changes and vice versa. This makes it easier to track changes.

Comment: To check for a change you would need to do `test.get()` which would give exactly the same result as `country.get()`.  Wouldn't both methods give the same result?  I'm still not quite understanding how it makes it easier to track changes.

Answer (score 2):

As Squall pointed out, to change the `StringVar` value you need to use its `set()` method.

On the other hand, the purpose of Tk Variables is to keep track of the values of the widgets they are connected to. The reason why you should prefer using a `StringVar` over reading the widget's value directly is that the latter is *thread-safe*.

Thread safety is a bit of a thorny topic for tkinter, but technically you should not be allowed to make modification to GUI elements in a thread different from the one that created the window (i.e. the original thread blocked in `mainloop()` **plus** the callbacks that you defined).

If you have an extra background thread that elaborates data and changes the UI accordingly using the `country.set("hello")` instruction might crash your application. Some systems forbid this entirely.

Meanwhile, setting the value in a `StringVar` is perfectly safe.

If you never use other threads and can work from callbacks alone, you will never face this problem and you might consider `StringVar` as a useless overhead. However, you will need to use variables for any kind of serious work.

Answer (score 0):

This was my first go at this method and I found myself here as well.
LOL I was curious as to why I must do that. I agreed that the .set method works a lot nicer in the code block. It's esthetically pleasing. It's just that sensible default.

I tried the above codes both failed. Language deprecation?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


master = tk.Tk()

country = ttk.Combobox(master)
country['values'] = ('USA', 'Canada', 'Australia')
country.pack()
```

## This does set a default value.

```
country.set("hello")

master.mainloop()
```