# How to convert a local variable into a global variable?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, button, combobox

This is a snippet of my code. I am trying to convert the local variable (`choice`) into a global variable so I can use the value it is holding later in the code, but I am unsure to how to do this. The code has no errors.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
cmb = ttk.Combobox(root, width="10",
values=("us","mexico","uk","france"))
cmb.place(relx="0.1",rely="0.1")

def checkcmbo():
    choice = cmb.get()

btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Get Value",command=checkcmbo)
btn.place(relx="0.5",rely="0.1")

URL='https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/'+choice+'/'
#this is where I need to use the value in the local variable

root.mainloop()

#Web scrapes the data containing the dates and daily deaths
URL='https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/'+choice+'/'
#### This is where I need to use the value in the local variable ####
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results=soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col-md-12"})
data=results[4]
script = data.find('script')
string = script.string
```

Comment: The code has no error,... code is working perfectly fine. What did you expect us to do? Actually what's your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert the local variable (choice) into a global variable so I would be able to use the value inside the local variable in other pieces of the code. sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: Where would you like to use that `choice`? If you want to use that inside function there there will be no issue!

Comment: the local variable choice, inside the function, holds the value the user picked from the combo box. I need to use the value the user picked later in the code as a variable (which isn't show in the example above as it is a snippet).

Comment: Add that part where you want to use that variable, so, that I can understand clearly. You can [edit] your question from here. @Teerath :)

Comment: ok thank you @Xitiz

Comment: I don't know. Why you want to use there but that URL line will run even before your GUI start, whereas that checkcmbo function will only run when you clicked on that `btn`. Please provide a complete Information why you want to use that there, there could be other best approach to use URL , I may hel you with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235637/discussion-between-teerath-and-xitiz).

Comment: Just provide little more code and explanation why you want to use that there, then the discussion in comment will end!

Comment: You are again confusing me, but now I will try to answer. :)

Comment: I added the extra code to the question above. I need the value in the choice variable to use it in a URL to web scrap information regarding COVID-19

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I only just now realized I was  able to up vote as I am still new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you do this :

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
cmb = ttk.Combobox(root, width="10", 
values=("us","mexico","uk","france"))
cmb.place(relx="0.1",rely="0.1")

def checkcmbo():
    URL='https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/'+cmb.get()+'/'
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    results=soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col-md-12"})
    data=results[4]
    script = data.find('script')
    string = script.string

btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Get Value",command=checkcmbo)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I hadn't saw your complete code, so I can't be sure but this should solve your problem.

Comment: Or if you have some `Label` to change after that scraping part then, `Label.config(text=string)`

Comment: Guess this was an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition of `choice` to global (keep it outside the function) and
Define your function like this:

```
choice = None # or any random initial value
def checkcmbo():
    global choice
    choice = cmb.get()
    print(choice)
```

The use of `global` tells python that the global variable `choice` can be edited inside that function.
However, if you just wanted to access a global variable (not edit it) you don't need to use the `global` keyword.

Comment: I am not sure why, but the global variable choice isn't updating it's value with the local variable choice

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should go with textvariables or `StringVar()`. To get its value, use `.get()` and tonset its value, use `.set('...')`

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar

...
cmb1=StringVar()
cmb = ttk.Combobox(root, width="10",textvariable=cmb1,
values=("us","mexico","uk","france")
cmb.place(relx="0.1",rely="0.1")

def checkcmbo():
    print(cmb1.get())

btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Get Value",command=checkcmbo)
btn.place(relx="0.5",rely="0.1")

....
```

Comment: Will that make any difference, cuz OP wants to that combobox value before even GUI start! Additionally read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37415603/12446721)